# Why sub instruction modifies the xpsr register and puts a carry flag for 9-7

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, stm32cubeide

I'm using STM32cubeIDE and debugging assembly on a cortex m4. I meet a strange behaviour when trying the instruction SUB. according to documentation,the SUB instruction shouldn't change the XPSR register. But when i use it, it does. Even for a no Carry operation like (9-7) it sets the XPSR carry flag to 1. Does any one understands this behaviour ?

Thx

I googled and read documentation but have no clue about this behaviour

Comment: Check which type of assembly syntax you are using.  If you have the line `.syntax unified` then `sub` does not modify flags and `subs` does.  In older versions of the language `sub` might set flags or not depending on the preceding instructions.  9-7 doesn't carry, you must have something else wrong.

Comment: Thx Tom, you're right i was on Thumb 16bits, and when switching to 32 SUB does no longer change the carry. For the fact that the carry flag is set whith subs without borrow, it seems to be normal. The carry flag is inverted with the sub instruction. found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065579/confusion-about-arm-documentation-on-carry-flag

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the thumb16 instructions modify the flags but 32bits instruction when using .syntax unified behave normally (SUB doesn't change the flags while SUBS do). For the carry, the documentation is incomplete. The carry flag is inverted for the subs instruction. more detail on [Confusion about ARM documentation on carry flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065579/confusion-about-arm-documentation-on-carry-flag)